# How to set R Path for integrate with Java

Tags: java, r, eclipse, rjava

```
I have done the following steps.


 1. install R -> Which is in C drive.
 2.open R-> install packages -> which is installed in 
    C:\Users\test.user\Documents\R
 3.open-> java project ->  right click(run configurations)->added new environment variable-> 
*"PATH":C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1\bin\i386,C:\Users\megala.p\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\rJava\jri**
```

4. Workplace default JRE -> jdk 1.8.0_45.

   After I have restarted the system and again tried to run application i got a below error:

   Cannot find JRI native library!
       Please make sure that the JRI native library is in a directory listed in java.library.path.

   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jri in java.library.path
           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1865)
           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
           at org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.(Rengine.java:19)
           at com.test.new.shared.ConfigureREngine.getREngineInstance(ConfigureREngine.java:19)

How can I configure java with R?

Comment: In R console can you try `system("java -help")` and  `if(Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")!="") Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="")`

Comment: it returns empty @ OdeToMyFiddle

Comment: My R installed kit is in programming files, and installed package is in Documents.... Is it correct or not? because I don't have write access into my drive. Or tell me how can i set java_home in R environment?